# Showing $\sum\limits_{p \in P} \frac{1}{p}$ where $P$ is the set of all primes is divergent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I've been reading proofs of this theorem, and I was wondering why the following is true:

We know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.  I'm not sure how knowing this fact leads us to the next step:

For any $M >0$ we can find primes $p_1,\cdots p_m$ such that $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{p_1^i}\right)\cdots \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{p_m^i}\right)>M.$

What I am saying is, given the opportunity, I would have never thought to look at a finite product of partial sums.  I understand why everything works after the above step.

Comment: What is $ k $ ?

Comment: Since $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, for some $N$ we have $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}\gt M$. Let the $p_i$ be all the primes less than $N$. Then your product is greater than $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}$. This is because when you expand you get all the $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n\le N$, plus some more terms.

Comment: Why are we taking them to powers?

Comment: Because some of the $\frac{1}{n}$ are products of powers of primes $\le$ the largest prime $\le N$. We use the unique factorization theorem.

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer and fleshing out the details for this step?

Comment: @Morris: I think it would benefit you to "flesh out the details" yourself as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This does not answer your question. I have changed the indices on your product. We start at $0$, not $1$. I believe that the altered indices are the "right" thing to use.

Let $M$ be any real number. Since $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, for some $N$ we have $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}\gt M$. Let the $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_m$ be **all** the primes $\le N$.

Now imagine expanding "your" (altered) product 
$$\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}\frac{1}{p_1^i}\right)\cdots \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}\frac{1}{p_m^i}\right).\tag{1}$$
We get all the $\frac{1}{k}$, where $k$ is a product of the form 
$$k=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m},$$
where the $a_i$ range independently over all numbers from $0$ to $N$, inclusive.

These $k$ include **all** integers in the interval from $1$ to $N$, plus possibly more. It follows that the product (1) is greater than or equal to (actually greater) than $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}$, and therefore (1) is greater than $M$.

Comment: Is this basically saying we are factoring $\sum\limits_{1}^{N} \frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Factoring each summand $1/k$.

Comment: So something like $1+1/2+1/3+1/(2 \cdot 2)+1/5+1/(2 \cdot 3)+\cdots + 1/k$

Comment: Sort of, except the factorization is of $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{k}$ plus other terms beyond $\frac{1}{k}$. But these additional terms make the product bigger, which is good.

Comment: Why would it include more?

Comment: Example, $N=4$: $(1+1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16)(1+1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81)=(1+1/2+1/3+1/4)$ plus other terms, so bigger than $1+1/2+1/3+1/4$.

Comment: Oh!  I see now.  The one thing I'm stuck on is why do we look at that product.  I still don't see the relationship of that product of sums of powers of primes and $\sum \frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: When you expand, you get all the terms $1/k$ up to $1/N$, plus usually a large bunch more. So the product is greater than the sum. The next part of the argument roughly says that powers greater than the first are not enough to account for the size, which means that the sum of the first power terms in the product, namely $\sum \frac{1}{p_i}$ is "big."

Comment: By the way, unfinished business. In your post, your exponents start at $1$. Is that *really* intended? The arguments for the divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{p}$ that I have seen use products of terms like $\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{1}{p_t^i}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $2\leq n\in \Bbb N$ let $S_n$ be the set of primes not exceeding $n.$ Let $x\in \Bbb N$ such that $2^x\geq n.$ $$\text {Let }\quad  V(n)= \prod_{p\in S_n}\left(\frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{p}}\right).$$ $$\text {Then }\quad V(n) =  \prod_{p\in S_n}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}p^{-j}>    \prod_{p\in S_n}\sum_{j=1}^xp^{-j}.$$ Completely expand the right-most expression above. For every $m\in \Bbb N$ with  $2\leq m\leq n,$ the term $\frac {1}{m}$ will appear in the expansion as the reciprocal of a product of powers of some of the members of $S_n.$   So we have $V(n)>1+\sum_{m=2}^{n+1}\frac {1}{m}.$ Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}V(n)=\infty.$

Let $\pi$ be the set of all primes. Then $$\prod_{p\in \pi}(1-\frac {1}{p})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{p\in S_n}(1-\frac {1}{p})=\lim_{n\to \infty}V(n)^{-1}=0. $$

Theorem. (Elementary). If $0\leq a_j<1$ for all $j\in \Bbb N$ then $$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1-a_j)=0\iff \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j=\infty.$$

We have $\prod_{p\in \pi}(1-\frac {1}{p})=0.$ By the above theorem we have $\sum_{p\in \pi}\frac {1}{p}=\infty.$

This is due to Leonhard Euler.